# Detecting device's IOS version with ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic application for android and IOS, the app display a message when specific action happen.

But i realized that there is a difference in this action if the IOS OS was higher than 11 or less than 10.

So i want to detect IOS' version, if it was less than 10 display this message and if it was higher then don't displau it.

I'm new to ionic, so how can i achive this?

**CODE:**

```
function (err) {
        if (err == "has no access to assets") {
            _this.presentAlert('no access');
        }
        else if (err == "no image selected") {
            _this.presentAlert('nothing selected');
        }

    });
```

The first if is where i want to check the device's OS version, if it was less than 11 then display the message.

How to do it?

Comment: Juste a little [search](https://www.qwant.com/?client=brz-moz&q=ionic+get+ios+version)  and you get your answer ...

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/utility/ionic.Platform/

Comment: detect.js file uses navigator.userAgent to detect the browser details and navigator.platform to detect operating system details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for version: `const currentPlatformVersion = ionic.Platform.version();`

if it is ios device `const isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();`

even this `const deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();` returns an object with the device that runs the ionic app.

Comment: I would recommend reading the official docs more since that is not so hard to know

Comment: I don't want to know if its IOS or not... I want to now the version of the IOS OS.. for example v10 or v11

Comment: did you try this const currentPlatformVersion = ionic.Platform.version(); ?

Comment: Thank you so much!